# different selector for parent child in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between:

```
li ul {color:red;}
```

and

```
li > ul {color:yellow;}
```

I try both and get the same result.

Comment: [Descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) - [Child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first selector is known as the [Descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)  whereas the second one is the [Child combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

**Descendant combinator**

```
li ul {color:red;}
```

> At times, authors may want selectors to describe an element that is
>   the descendant of another element in the document tree (e.g., "an EM
>   element that is contained within an H1 element"). Descendant
>   combinators express such a relationship. A descendant combinator is
>   whitespace that separates two sequences of simple selectors. A
>   selector of the form "A B" represents an element B that is an
>   arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

**Child combinators**

```
li > ul {color:yellow;}
```

> A child combinator describes a childhood relationship between two
>   elements. A child combinator is made of the "greater-than sign"
>   (U+003E, >) character and separates two sequences of simple selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The first selector covers all ul inside li.

The second cover only the direct ul descendant inside li.

For more selectors tips, [see this links](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: There is no such thing as "child" and "direct child". You mean "descendant" and "child".

Comment: Thank you, interesting page